# How to make REST call asynchronous in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, asynchronous, callback

I have REST calls between two microservices, one of the call is taking more than 15 mins of time to complete. We have company's own private cloud implementation which is terminating any open connection kept for more than 15 mins.

We are looking for some asynchronous rest call implementation, where service A will trigger the rest call to service B and forget and service B will notify when the response is ready to be served.
Is there any widely used technique/API for such scenario? I was not able to find any thing concrete on this front.

Comment: use any messaging system here kafka,sqs,RabbitMq

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the actual resources, create a temporary one. Instead of returning a 201 (Created) HTTP response, you can issue a 202 (Accepted) response code. This informs the client that the request has been accepted and understood by the server, but the resource is not (yet) created. Send the temporary resource inside the Location header.

Request:

```
POST /blogs HTTP/1.1
<xml>
    blogdata
</xml>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Location: /queue/12345
```

This location can store information about the status of the actual resource: an ETA on when it will be created, what is currently being done or processed.

When the actual resource has been created, the temporary resources can return a 303 (See other) response. The location header returns the URI to the definitive resource. A client can either DELETE the temporary resource, or the server can expire this resource and return a 410 (Gone) later on.

Source: https://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Polling. Something like this :

Service A triggers a Rest call to Service B which returns an OK response. Then in each 1 minute service A make another API request to another endpoint in Service B which would return status of the previous request until the process is completed or for may be a certain point of time. Now when the 2nd request send the status as success you can mark the process as completed.